# "$ rails s" gives following error

Tags: railsapps

/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/format (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
    from /Users/jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:14:in`initialize'
    from /Users/jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:6:in `new'
    from /Users/jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:6:in`evaluate'
    from /Users/jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
    from /Users/jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:138:in`definition'
    from /Users/jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:126:in `load'
    from /Users/jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:110:in`setup'
    from /Users/jay/project_mon/config/boot.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in`'

Comment: Have you tried making a brand new rails app, "rails new my_app" and tried "rails s"? If there is still a problem, it looks like it is with RVM, I'd recommend reinstalling.

Comment: Hi Vasseurth, thanks for advise, I've done exactly what you said. Delete all previous installation and it is working fine.